# Tastypie sanitize input?

Tags: django, tastypie

What would be the most effective way to sanitize a user's input using Tastypie? Right now, if a user enters something like **hi**, the HTML tags get saved, so when it is displayed, the text is displayed as bold. How would I sanitize all input besides changing the obj_create for each resource?

Also, since I am a newb at web security, should I be sanitizing a user's input at the front end, too? I am not sure if I should sanitize the input before sending the POST request to the tastypie API or if I should sanitize the input when tastypie is processing the input?

Edit: I did find out that I can escape HTML in my underscore templates by displaying data with <%- %> rather than <%= %>. Why doesn't underscore do this by default? I feel like it is a big security risk.
If I accidentally forget to do this somewhere, then I am screwed.

I think the above fixes the front end security problem, but what about the back end? Is there a way I can see if I am vulnerable to SQL injections? Will tastypie sanitize input when I do a POST/PUT request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never, Ever, Ever render untrusted user input to the browser. The only way you're seeing that in the browser is if you have `|safe` on the output filter. Don't do that. Don't set the property as mark_safe=True in the model either.

Comment: By filtering with |safe, are you referring to Django templates? I am not using Django templates to render my models. I am using underscore templates. Also, I do not have mark_safe=True in the model, so how is it that the HTML tags are going through? I would understand if underscore didn't escape the HTML, but wouldn't Django not store the HTML tags?

Comment: Nevermind about the above comment. I made an edit to the original post.

Comment: I stand by my comment. Django by default never ever displays unsafe content. I wouldn't alter the input before storing it in the DB, I just wouldn't display it. Good to know it's underscore with the bad defaults and not us! :) There are no known SQL injection vulnerabilities in django core or tastypie resulting from unsafe input. We escape things properly before calling the SQL

Answer (score 0):

I added a dehydrate method to the resource that overwrote the dangerous field on it's way to the browser, like so:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['field_to_sanitize'] = bundle.data['field_to_sanitize'].replace("&", "&amp;").replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;").replace("'", "&#39;").replace('"', "&quot;")
    return bundle
```

Now, this isn't the best solution, but it will escape many of the most dangerous entities. If you have a htmlescape function handy, you can use that.